# SharePoint/PnP/PowerShell: Update the workflow subscription by setting it to enabled to false

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I try to update the "Enabled" property of a workflow subscription in SharePoint with PnP PowerShell but nothing append.
My goal is to set programmaticaly this action as in UI when you can navigate to the Remove Workflow (RemWrkfl.aspx) page end then choose "No New Instances".
Here it is what I do:

```
Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -DisableNameChecking
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "web_site_url"
$wfs = Get-PnPWorkflowSubscription -Name "WF_Name" -List "Lists/list_Name"
$wfs.Enable = $false
```

After this last command, I don't know what I need to do to activate this new property.
Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is available here: [SharePoint Online/PnP/PowerShell: Update the workflow subscription by setting it to enabled to false](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/SharePoint-Online-PnP-PowerShell-Update-the-workflow/m-p/901897)